# Dynamic scheduling across OpenMP thread teams

Tags: multithreading, openmp

I am curious why OpenMP (v4.5) specification does not provide dynamic scheduling across thread teams.
Is it possible to schedule loop iterations across OpenMP thread teams at runtime, using Nvidia GPUs or Intel Xeon Phis?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give a code example?

Comment: I *think* the question is about the distribute statement and is questioning the reasoning for the restriction in 2.10.8 in the OpenMP 4.5 spec that says "If dist_schedule is specified, kind must be static. ". But, I may be wrong.

Comment: Yes, like @JimCownie said, my question is about the 'dist_schedule' clause of 'distribute' construct. Only 'static' scheduling is allowed in 'dist_schedule'. Why not 'dynamic' scheduling? Is there any reason that dynamic scheduling is not allowed in the OpenMP 4.5 specification?